# Implementing multiple threads in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I am pretty new to Java and the project I have requires a new thread to be created every time the user presses a button.  I've worked with the MVC and Swing but I am trying to find a way to create however many threads the user needs.  I reviewed some information and was trying to use an arrayList to just collect all the threads.  However I am having some problems with this:

```
private ThreadLibrary thread_lib = new ThreadLibrary(); 

    public TestArray(int val) {
        for (int i=0; i < val; i++) {           
            thread_lib.addThread(    new Thread(new runThread()).start()   );       
        }
    }
```

Since the *new* operator doesn't return anything it won't add anything to the arrayList.  Any ideas or a better data structure to use?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new` definitely returns whatever you're constructing. It's the `start` method which returns `void`. Try storing the thread object in a variable and kicking it off separately.

```
public TestArray(int val) {
    for (int i = 0; i < val; i++) {       
        Thread thread = new Thread(new runThread());
        thread.start();
        thread_lib.addThread(thread);       
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help and the clarification on what is returning void.

Answer (score 1):

This,

```
thread_lib.addThread(    new Thread(new runThread()).start()   )
```

should be,

```
Thread t =  new Thread(new runThread());
thread_lib.addThread(t);
t.start();
```

Instead of doing this, look at the [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) class

Comment: one more question.  Is there an easy way to pass any paramters to the runThread class?  If I put it in new runthread() it shouldn't really be usable since  t.start will kick off the run() method.

Comment: Ok - it seems to work but I guess don't really understand why.  I assume it runs the constructor before it becomes a thread and goes to run().  Not sure if that will work for me in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

`new` does indeed return the `Thread`; it's the call to `start()` that returns void. You can simply do this in two steps:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new runThread());
t.start();
thread_lib.addThread(t);
```

Now, whether you actually need to put these in an array or not is open to question; there isn't too much you can do to a Thread after it's running.